# Parameter type validation in functions - binary modules vs. script modules

Tags: c#, powershell, type-conversion

Having built a number of PowerShell modules (both binary and script), there's still an inconsistency between the two models that I cannot quite get my head around. Perhaps one of you could shed some light on this matter.

1. Imagine a function that accepts a single `DateTime` value. In a script function, I would define this as a `[DateTime]` parameter; in the C# function the parameter would be of type `DateTime`. So far, so good.
2. Now imagine passing a `DateTime` to the function, to which an additional note property has been added using `Add-Member`. Despite being defined as a `[DateTime]`, the script function parameter would gladly accept this value, since it's actually a `PSObject` wrapping the original `DateTime` (and potentially containing additional members) which is unwrapped upon use - I hope I'm using the correct terminology here. As expected, passing something other than a (wrapped) `DateTime` would fail, thus making the function more or less type-safe.
3. The equivalent C# function defines the parameter as a `DateTime`, so AFAIK it has no way to access the additional parameter. After all, the only "interface" that the parameter provides comes from the `DateTime` type.
4. Alternatively, I could define the C# function's parameter type as a `PSObject`, but then I would have to do my own type checking for the `PSObject`'s `BaseObject`.

Is there a flaw in my logic? Or, more importantly, is there a way around this, so that I can still leave my binary module's type checking to PowerShell?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're both right and wrong - it entirely depends on whether the target parameter is of a value type (`System.DateTime` is a struct for example) - in which case everything is lost on type coercion during parameter binding.

If, however, the parameter type is of a reference type you can "resurrect" the PSObject wrapper using [`PSObject.AsPSObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.psobject.aspsobject).

*I came up with the following example in pure(-ish) PowerShell for ease of replicability, but I believe it adequately shows my point*

Paste the following into a C# source file (say, `TestCmdlets.cs`):

```
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace TestPSObject
{
  // This will be our parameter type
  public class TestObject {}

  // This will be our reference type test cmdlet
  [Cmdlet(VerbsDiagnostic.Test, "PSObjectByRef")]
  public class TestPSObjectByRefCommand : Cmdlet
  {
    [Parameter(Mandatory=true)]
    public TestObject TestObject
    {
      get { return testObject; }
      set { testObject = value; }
    }
    private TestObject testObject;

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
      // If this works, we should receive an object with
      // identical psextended properties
      WriteObject(PSObject.AsPSObject(this.TestObject));
    }
  }

  // This will be our value type test cmdlet
  [Cmdlet(VerbsDiagnostic.Test, "PSObjectByValue")]
  public class TestPSObjectByValueCommand : Cmdlet
  {
    [Parameter(Mandatory=true)]
    public DateTime DateTime
    {
      get { return dateTime; }
      set { dateTime = value; }
    }
    private DateTime dateTime;

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
      // If this works, we should receive an object with
      // identical psextended properties (hint: we won't)
      WriteObject(PSObject.AsPSObject(this.DateTime));
    }
  }
}
```

Now, in your shell, compile and import our test module:

```
Add-Type -Path .\TestCmdlets.cs -OutputAssembly TestPSObject.dll -OutputType Library
Import-Module .\TestPSObject.dll
```

Next up we create our test subjects and add a note property to them:

```
$TestObject = New-Object TestPSObject.TestObject
$TestObject |Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name TestProperty -Value "Hi there!"
$DateTime = Get-Date
$DateTime |Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name TestProperty -Value "Hi there!"
```

They now both return the string value `Hi there!` when you dereference the `TestProperty` member.

Now for the actual test:

```
$TestObjectAfter = Test-PSObjectByRef -TestObject $TestObject
$DateTimeAfter   = Test-PSObjectByValue -DateTime $DateTime
```

This will still return `Hi there!`:

```
$TestObjectAfter.TestProperty
```

But this will not:

```
$DateTimeAfter.TestProperty
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your elaborate answer! It's totally clear now. I feel a bit silly for having had to ask this, but I'm very glad I did! :-)

Comment: @JanHoek Happy to help! Ain't no such thing as silly questions ;-)